# For $z \in \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $|z| > 1$, show that $z_n = \frac{z^n}{n}$ diverges to $\infty$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $|z| > 1$.

It is required to show that $z_n = \frac{z^n}{n}$ diverges to $\infty$.

I already tried to show that for $w \in \mathbb{C}$, there is $\epsilon > 0$ s.t. for every $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there is $n \ge N$ s.t. $|z_n - w| \ge \epsilon$, but I couldn't find the requested values.

I also tried that $d(\sigma(z_n), \infty) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, where $\sigma: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{S}^2$ is the Stereographic projection, but I failed too.

Also is not easy to show $\Re{(z)} \to \infty$ and $\Im{(z)} \to \infty$, since I don't know which is the appropriate form of $z$ one should take.

I also look for some result similar to the Monotone Convergent Sequences, but couldn't fine a similar result for complex numbers, since there is no orden in $\mathbb{C}$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The real sequence $|z_n|=|z|^n/n$ is not bounded if $|z|>1$ so the complex sequence $(z_n)$ diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: By this way, it is required to prove that $|z_n|$ is monotone, right?

Comment: it is not sufficient because a monotone positive sequence could converge, it has to be shown that $|z_n| \to \infty$ for $n \to \infty$

Comment: I mean, it should be required to prove that $|z_n|$ is monotone and non-bounded.

Comment: Yes. Unbounded is not sufficient to tell that the sequence diverges to infinity.

Comment: @donovan The correct way to prove the sequence divergence with this idea is to show that there is a natural $N$ such that for every $n \ge N$, $\frac{|z^n|}{n} > r$, for $r$ an arbitrary real. This condition is stronger than the non-boundness of the sequence. For example $(1,0,2,0,3,0,4,…)$ is not bounded but the limit is not determined. But I really appreciate it sir.

Comment: @BlueTomato that’s correct as pointed out by Yathiraj, unboundness give us divergence only and not divergence to $\infty$

Answer (score 1):

For any real $a>1$, consider the function:
$$f(x) = \frac{a^x}{x}.$$
By L'Hospital's, we can easily see that
$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{a^x \log_e a}{1} = \infty.$$
Note that $a> 1$ is required for $\log a>0$. What does this imply? You choose any sequence approaching infinity, say $\{n\}$, then $\{f(a_n)\}$ should also approach infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c=|z|-1$. Then $c>0$ and by the binomial theorem, $|z_n|=\left|\frac{z^n}{n}\right|=\frac{(1+c)^n}{n}>\frac{\binom{n}{2}c^2}{n}=\frac{(n-1)c^2}{2}$ when $n\geq2$. Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}|z_n|=\infty$, i.e., $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\displaystyle f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{z^n}$. Then $f$ is holomorphic for $|z|>1$, being the sum of a geometric series.

Therefore, $f'$ is holomorphic for $|z|>1$ and $\displaystyle f’(z)=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{n}{z^{n+1}}$ and so $\displaystyle-zf'(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{n}{z^{n}}$.

Since the series converges, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{n}{z^n} =0$, which proves the claim.